# Simple Ajax Post to PHP echo

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have the following code on product.php .. can't seem to echo post variable from ajax post. Alert displays fine. Please help

JQUERY

```
    document.getElementById("LBTest").onchange = function(){
      var lbtest = $('#LBTest :selected').val();
      $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "product.php",
      data: {test: lbtest},
      success: function()
      {
          alert("Successful");
      }
      });
}
```

PHP

```
if(isset($_POST['test'])){
    $data = $_POST['test'];
    echo $data;
}
```

Comment: maybe the problem is your url. does product.php is located alongside your jquery?

Comment: You need to assign the Ajax results to go somewhere

Answer (score 4):

You need to do something with the data you receive from the ajax call. For example, to put the result into a `<div>` called `resultDiv`:

```
success: function(data)
{
  $('#resultDiv').html(data);
  alert("Successful");
}
```

Comment: If `alert` is not included after changing the text in `<div id='resultDiv'>`, the change only blinks in the HTML. Do you know how to freeze the change? Thanks.-

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "product.php",
      data: {test: lbtest},
      success: function(data)
      {
          alert("Successful");
      }
});
```

You need to **add the data to the success function that is called**. You can do this locally or reference another function meant to handle responses coming back from the server.

```
success: function(data)
{
    console.log(data);
    alert(data + " was returned from the server");
}
```

It is a good idea on the server side to json_encode the objects that are being returned and using error codes that can be more appropriately handled on the client.

```
handleResponse(data) {
    var data = $.parseJSON(data);
    if(data.code >= 200 || data.code < 300) {
        // modify the dom, add data to a model, take over the world with your web app.
    }
}
```